# How to fix this bizarre ConfigurationSection exceptions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, configuration, app-config, configuration-files

I was tasked with making this third party software run on our server, but we only have partial access to the code, the rest exists only as pre-compiled libraries.
One of those libraries throws enigmatic exceptions and I can't figure out why. I am completely oblivious to Visual Studio and C#, and this is making no sense at all to me.

What I initially get is:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Unhandled Exception:   System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'GroupsImporter.Program' threw an exception. --->
>
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration
>   system failed to initialize --->
>
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: **Unrecognized
>   configuration section ThirdPartyCompany.Framework.Core.Configuration.v1.2.
>   (Y:\path-to-executable\GroupsImporter.exe.Config line 67)**
>
> at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean
>   ignoreLocal)
>
> at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors
>   schemaErrors)
>
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String
>   configKey)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The configuration file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="AdWordsApi" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
        <section name="AdWords.Common.Configuration" type="AdWords.Common.Configuration.AdWordsConfiguration, AdWords.Common"/>
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        ...
    </appSettings>

    <AdWords.Common.Configuration Budget ="xxx" CPC="xxx" EstoqueMinimo="x">
        ...
    </AdWords.Common.Configuration>

    <AdWordsApi>
        ...
    </AdWordsApi>

    <system.web>
        ...
    </system.web>

    <system.net>
        ...
    </system.net>

    <ThirdPartyCompany.Framework.Core.Configuration.v1.2>
        ...
    </ThirdPartyCompany.Framework.Core.Configuration.v1.2>
</configuration>
```

In turn if I remove the section it is complaining about, I get this:

> Unhandled Exception:   System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'GroupsImporter.Program' threw an exception. --->
>
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationException: **Configuraton section
>   ThirdPartyCompany.Framework.Core.Configuration.v1.2 could not be
>   found.**
>
> at ThirdPartyCompany.Framework.Core.Guard.Against[TException](Boolean
>   assertion, String message)
>
> at
>   ThirdPartyCompany.Framework.Core.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.GetConfiguration()
>
> at
>   ThirdPartyCompany.Framework.Core.IoCContainerWrapper.Implementation.IoCThirdPartyCompanyContainer.loadRegisterConfiguration()
>
> //And the stack goes on...

I have no idea on how to solve this issue. I don't have access to the code where the ServiceConfig class is implemented or where the config is consumed.
Any ideas about what is going on, and how to fix this issue?

Edit: It was supposedly working on the company's server exactly as provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you need to add the section to the `configSections` tag.

So, exactly like this one:

```
<section name="AdWordsApi"
```

...but you also need:

```
<section name="ThirdPartyCompany.Framework.Core.Configuration.v1.2" ...
```

Comment: I suspected so, but I have no idea on what to put as type. If I do it but ommit the type I get a: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The 'type' attribute must be specified on the 'section' tag.

Comment: The type is the fully qualified name of whatever type handles that configuration section. It probably resides in the third party assembly. Can you not reference their website or documentation or something?

Comment: Oh, not that kind of third-party :) No documentation whatsoever. Any other way of finding out that type? Maybe the symbol can be extracted from the library somehow?

Comment: You will just have to open the assembly in an assembly viewer and browse through until you find something that looks like it is what you are after. You can base your assumption of what it looks like on the types that handle the AdWords stuff.

Comment: Yeah, seems like the only option. Thank you Simon. Are you positive that this is the source of those exceptions?

Comment: I was able to retrieve the type and add the section, it works now. Thanks Simon.

Answer (score 1):

You must be sure that you reference those libraries or ask which one implements the class "ConfigurtionSection" that the system complains about.

Can't post answers: Yeah, the only way you can add custom configuration sections (not app keys) as far as I know is by inheriting from ConfigurationSection class

Comment: I was under the impression that they are being referenced. Do you have reason to believe that this is a dependency issue?

Comment: Hum... That's odd, because I'm referencing (to my knowledge) all the libraries. Maybe I'm missing one? The exception cites one that I would bet is the one in question, that I'm referencing already: ThirdPartyCompany.Framework.Core.Configuration.ConfigurationSection

Comment: @rgcalsaverini try making a new project, reference all the dlls and see if it runs, just to be sure

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with a different dll, the message was:
**"Unrecognized configuration section AdWordsApi"**

I fix it reinstalling the references AdWordsApi using nuget console.

*From Nuget Package Manager Console* execute:
`Install-Package Google.AdWords`

It will reinstall the package and add the following code in app.config

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="AdWordsApi" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" />  
  </configSections>
```